# Budget android phone to upgrade to from an iPhone 5S

Tags: android, smartphones

**Idk if this is the right site to ask, correct me if im wrong :)**

I'm about to change my iPhone 5S to some android based phone. My budget is about 150$. I'm from Belarus, so that might affect what phones are available for me. I'm looking at a Redmi Note 7 for around $130 dollars. I was wondering if there are better phones out there that would work for what I need. I am okay with getting a used phone also.

The phone should be <=6.2", with fingerprint sensor ofc, and a good battery life

The phone needs to be comfortable for me to use, 4G capabilities (Don't want to downgrade in download/upload speeds)

Comment: You should provide us with as many requirements as you can think of, otherwise your question may be hard to answer because it may be too broad. So far you have just told us a price and OS.

Comment: @Romen well these are main requirements the phone should just be comfortable to use, i don't really care bout perfomace

Comment: Please edit the question to add information, some people will miss it in the comments.

Comment: Define comfortable to use, please because this could include the size of the phone for some users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would get a Redmi Note 7 or an iPhone 8 or higher. Just be aware that the iPhone X and 11 series substitutes the fingerprint for an facial scanner  which I love on my iPhone Xr. It unlocks my phone almost immediately.

Answer (score 0):

**Redmi A3**

This is another option for your budget as compact phone.

Processor
Qualcomm® Snapdragon™ 665 AIE
Octa-core Kryo™ 260 CPU, up to 2.0 GHz
Adreno™ 610 GPU
11nm FinFET process
Memory
4GB+64GB / 6GB+128GB

Expandable storage up to 256GB
RAM: Dual channel LPDDR4x
ROM: UFS 2.1 flash storage
*Available storage and RAM are less than the total memory due to storage of the operating system and software pre-installed in the device.

Battery & Charging
4030mAh (typ) / 3940mAh (min)
Supports Quick Charge™ 3.0 Techonology and 18W
Fast Charge
In-box 10W charger
Type-C charging port
Built-in rechargeable battery

Rear Camera
48MP AI Smart Triple Rear Camera
48MP primary camera
• Sony IMX586 sensor
• 1.6μm 4-in-1 Super Pixel
• 6pcs lens, ƒ/1.79
• 1/2 inch sensor size, PDAF
8MP ultra wide-angle camera
• FOV 118°, ƒ/2.2, FF
2MP depth camera
• AI portrait mode
• Steady handheld night photography

Video features
4K video, 30fps
1080p, 60fps/30fps
720p, 30fps
EIS, 1080p, 30 fps; 720p, 30 fps
Slow motion recording, 720p, 240fps/120fps; 1080p, 120fps
AI Scene detection
Detects up to 27 different scenes

Front Camera
32MP AI Selfie Camera
1.6μm 4-in-1 Super Pixel Design
In-screen fingerprint sensor
5 pcs lens, ƒ/2.0, 79° FOV, FF
AI face unlock
Panorama selfie
Video features
1080p, 30fps
720p, 30fps
Short video recording
AI Scene detection
Detects up to 12 different scenes
Unlock
7th Gen In-screen fingerprint unlock
AI Face unlock

Display
15.46cm (6.08) Super AMOLED Display
19.5:9 aspect ratio
HD+ display (1560 x 720)
Contrast ratio: 60000:1 (min)
Color gamut: NTSC 102.7% (typ) 3D glass, rounded display corners
Corning® Gorilla® Glass 5
Dimensions
Height: 153.48mm
Width: 71.85mm
Thickness: 8.475mm
Weight: 173.8g

Network & Connectivity
4G Dual SIM
3-choose-2 SIM slot
* When using both SIM card slots, either card can
be set as the primary card, which supports
4G+/4G/3G/2G calling and data
Network bands
GSM: B2/3/5/8 
WCDMA: B1/2/4/5/8 
TDD-LTE: 40/41(2535-2655MHz)
FDD-LTE: B1/3/5/8

Connectivity
Supports protocols: 802.11a/b/g/n/ac
Supports 2.4G WiFi / Supports 5G WiFi / Supports
WiFi Direct
Supports WiFi Display
Supports Bluetooth 5.0
IR remote
Ports
USB Type-C charging port
3.5mm headphone port
Navigation & Positioning
GPS | AGPS | GLONASS | Beidou
Sensors
Gyroscope | Accelerometer | Distance sensor | Electronic compass | Vibration motor | IR blaster | Ambient light sensor | Gravity sensor

Multimedia Support
MP4 | M4V | MKV | XVID | WAV | AAC | MP3 | FLAC | AMR
Supports H.264 (Baseline / Main / High profile), MPEG4 (Simple profile / ASP) and other video formats.
Supports audio formats such as PCM, AAC / AAC + / eAAC +, MP3, AMR - NB and WB, FLAC, WAV.

Audio
Large 0.915cc speaker box
High audio output amplified by Smart PA

Package Contents
Net Quantity 1 U
1 U Contains:
Mobile Phone 1 U , 
Adapter 1 U , 
USB Type-C Cable 1 U , 
SIM Eject Tool 1 U , 
User Guide 1 U , 
Warranty Card 1 U , 
Soft Case 1 U

Answer (score 0):

my choice for the specifications that you made has got to be blu vivo XL5